# Vigenere cipher C++

Tags: c++, cryptography, vigenere

HZVIG.cpp:

```
#include "HZVIG.h"

char ROTEncode(char inchar, int rot)
{
    if (IsBigLetter(inchar))
        return ((int)inchar - (int)'A' + rot) % 26 + 'A' - 1;
    else if (IsSmallLetter(inchar))
        return ((int)inchar - (int)'a' + rot) % 26 + 'a' - 1;
    else
        return inchar;
}
char ROTDecode(char inchar, int rot)
{
    if (IsBigLetter(inchar))
        return ((int)inchar - (int)'A' - rot + 26) % 26 + 'A' - 1;
    else if (IsSmallLetter(inchar))
        return ((int)inchar - (int)'a' + rot + 26) % 26 + 'a' - 1;
    else
        return inchar;
}
std::string VIGDecode(std::string instring, std::string key)
{
    std::string result;
    for (int i = 0; i < instring.length(); i++)
        result += ROTDecode(instring[i], key[i % key.length()] - 'A' + 1);
    return result;
}
std::string VIGEncode(std::string instring, std::string key)
{
    std::string result;
    for (int i = 0; i < instring.length(); i++)
        result += ROTEncode(instring[i], key[i % key.length()] - 'A' + 1);
    return result;
}
```

HZVIG.h:

```
#include <string>

#define IsBigLetter(a) a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z'
#define IsSmallLetter(a) a >= 'a' && a <= 'z'

std::string VIGDecode(std::string instring, std::string key);
std::string VIGEncode(std::string instring, std::string key);
```

This code works, but has wrong output:

```
C:\Users\adm1n\Desktop\C\HZToolkit>HZToolkit --evig --key ALPHA HZU18{CLASSICAL_CIPHER}
HKJ18{NAHSSTRHL_NXWHEC}
```

It should be: HKJ18{JLADHPCAW_RPPHPG}
I think input is ok, something goes wrong in functions.
C:\Users\adm1n\Desktop\C\HZToolkit>HZToolkit --evig --key ALPHA ALPHA
Outputs: AWEOA

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think this is wrong? Note that even if the plaintext is not a letter, you still "advance" the key (at least, that's what your program currently does).

Lining up the plain text and duplicating the key:

```
     Plain: HZU18{CLASSICAL...
       Key: ALPHAALPHAALPHA...
            ^        ^^   ^
   You get: HKJ18{NAHSSTRHL...
You expect: HKJ18{JLADHPCAW...
```

Note the places marked with `^`: those are where the key equals `A`, so no encryption takes place (the plaintext letter becomes the ciphertext letter).

Seems fine to me.

(The decryption is broken though. As a hint, note that `ROTDecode` doesn't treat lowercase and uppercase letters in the same way).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I understood what is wrong: functions should ignore non-alphabet symbols.